# xmlhttp.open does not seem to do anything in MVC structure

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm trying to add an auto-complete function to a text field.
This used to work, but then I switched to an MVC structure and now I can't get it back to work.

PHP/HTML:

```
echo '<br><br>Add member:<br>'
    . '<form method="post"><input type="text" name="username" oninput="findUsers(this.value)" list="livesearch">'
    . '<datalist id="livesearch"></datalist>'
    . '<input type="submit" value="Add">'
    . '</form>';
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
function findUsers(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = "no suggestions";
        xmlhttp.send();
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","/user/search/?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

/user/search opens a function called search in the class User in the UserController.php file

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
public function search()
    {
        $response = "hello";
        echo $response;
    }
}
```

So this should put the "hello" message in the livesearch datalist.
But for some reason just nothing is happening.
If I replace the xmlhttp.open by window.open, the page does load normally and shows the hello message. But that is obviously not what I want.

---

**Figured out the exact problem:**

My xmlhttp.responseText is also returning the header of my website, which is already loaded in the MVC structure.

How would I work around this?
Is it an option to just edit the string and get the last part in javascript?
Or are there better solutions?

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work"? are you getting an error, or are you not seeing the expected result? if it's the latter, it could be a problem with your xmlhttp.onreadystatechange listener, what does that look like?

Comment: it's not showing the expected result

Comment: @hairraisin updated my post

Comment: So does the function get called? Is the status something other than 200?

Comment: when I add an else to the status check I get 3 replies: 0, 200, 200

Comment: well a datalist should have `option` elements, you are not adding that.

Comment: when I show the responsetext it shows a whole bunch of html code, guess that's where the problem is, not sure how to fix that though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used JavaScript to grab the last part of the string (so without the header)
It does what it's supposed to do now, but feels like a pretty "dirty" solution.

Also had to add the `<option value="">` tag, which was in my code, but not in my testcode.